# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Tags: c, stack-smash

I'm trying to print maximum value of array elements. Programm compiles fine, but when I input array values I get this message *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated. What I did wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int get_max(int ar[5]) {
        int i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
}
int max = ar[0];
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    if (max < ar[i])
        max = ar[i];
    }
}
    return max;
}
int main() {
        int a;
        int k;
    k = get_max(&a);
    printf("%d",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you pass an address to "int" to a function that expect 5 elements array.

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating space for one `int`, passing the address of that to the function, and trying to treat it as an array of five `int`s.

If you want to pass an array, declare an array.

But really, there seems to be no point to declaring `a` in `main()` at all, and passing it to the function. Just declare the array locally in the function.